# Can't create "animation buttons" in python

Tags: python, animation

I can't create button, that moves or animate the ball on  the screen.
It gives an error : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/talap/Desktop/python/automatikusanimacio.py", line 43, in 
    Button(abl1,text='Indít',command=abl1.start_it).pack()
  File "C:\Users\talap\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1948, in **getattr**
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'start_it'

Here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/J7qZ3ZGt

Comment: firstly, you need to redo your formatting, and secondly you created the function `start_it` as a global function, yet you are trying to call it as if it belongs to your GUI, try changing `abl1.start_it` to `start_it`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it works! :)

Comment: How can I add a tick to your comment?(James Kent)

Comment: until you get a certain level of reputation you can't upvote a comment, you can only mark an answer as being an accepted answer, i'll resubmit my comment as an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to redo your formatting.
I'd suggest you read [this formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

The problem here is that you created the function `start_it` as a global function, yet you are trying to call it as if it belongs to your GUI, try changing `abl1.start_it` to `start_it`